# Desired State Configuration xWebsite

Tags: powershell, winrm, dsc

I am running into a problem. When I go to create a website I get an error. Has anyone else ever ran into this issue?

VERBOSE: [CONT10SQLTEST]:                            [[xWebsite]CMSAuth] Physical Path of Website CMSAuth does not match the desired state.
Cannot find path 'IIS:\Sites\CMSAuth' because it does not exist.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (IIS:\Sites\CMSAuth:) [], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand
    + PSComputerName        : CONT10SQLTEST

VERBOSE: [CONT10SQLTEST]: LCM:  [ End    Test     ]  [[xWebsite]CMSAuth]  in 1.9830 seconds.
The PowerShell provider MSFT_xWebsite threw one or more non-terminating errors while running the Test-TargetResource functionality. These errors are logged to the ETW channel called 
Microsoft-Windows-DSC/Operational. Refer to this channel for more details.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NonTerminatingErrorFromProvider
    + PSComputerName        : CONT10SQLTEST

VERBOSE: [CONT10SQLTEST]: LCM:  [ End    Set      ]
The SendConfigurationApply function did not succeed.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (root/Microsoft/...gurationManager:String) [], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 1
    + PSComputerName        : CONT10SQLTEST

```
configuration iis
{
     node $env:computername
     {

          xWebsite CMSAuth
          {
               Ensure = "Present"
               Name = "CMSAuth"
               State = "Started"
               ApplicationPool = "CMSAuthAppPool"
               PhysicalPath = "E:\websites\CMSAuth\Website"
               BindingInfo = MSFT_xWebBindingInformation
                        {
                            Protocol = "HTTP"
                            Port = 80
                            HostName = "*"
                        }

          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen it.

I am using DSC Resource wave 4 / WebAdministration 1.2.

I fixed it by going in to the MSFT_xWebsite.psm1 file and replacing:
`$Website = Get-Website -Name $Name` with `$Website = Get-Website | Where Name -eq $Name`

`Get-Website -Name $Name` returns all websites on the host, so the library thinks the site exists, but then fails when getting the properties in `Test-TargetResource`

I loaded the module directly, using `Import-Module MSFT_xWebsite.psm1`, and executed the functions to figure out what was failing. The error I got running the module function directly helped me find the failing catch block via the error message. The line numbers were still useless.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Looks like this has been fixed but not yet released: https://github.com/PowerShell/xWebAdministration/pull/50

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to edit the module yourself as described in the answer above, you can use the corresponding module [cWebAdministration](https://github.com/PowerShellOrg/cWebAdministration) from PowerShell.org. It fixes the issue and can be imported alongside xWebAdministration if you need more modules than the two of cWebAdministration (cWebSite and cAppPool):

```
Import-DscResource -ModuleName cWebAdministration
Import-DscResource -ModuleName xWebAdministration
```

Comment: This was for DSC Powershell 3.5 which had this issue. The module has been resolved with DSC Powershell 4.0. However, thank you for additional information.

Comment: The bug has indeed been fixed in a release available on [GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/xWebAdministration). I was using the last version from [TechNet](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/xWebAdministration-Module-3c8bb6be), where it is no longer maintained.